# Accent / PHP / Javascript / Uncaught SyntaxError Unexpected Identifier

Tags: php, javascript, function, diacritics

I have a problem with my PHP/JavaScript and accent. When I give a variable who contain an accent, the JavaScript's console say : Uncaught SyntaxError Unexpected Identifier.

**PHP:**

```
foreach($credit as $k => $v)
{
    $id = $credit[$k]->id_credit;
    $nom = $credit[$k]->nom_credit;
    $prix = $credit[$k]->prix_credit;
    echo "<a onClick='modification(".$id.",".$nom.",".$prix.");'>" . Image::resize('images/credit/' . $credit[$k]->id_credit . "." . $credit[$k]->format_image_credit,100,100) . "</a>";
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function modification(id,nom,prix)
{
    var div = document.getElementById('modifCredit').style.display = 'block';
    alert(id + " " + nom + " " + prix);
}
```

Without `$nom`, all works. And If I replace :

```
 $nom = $credit[$k]->nom_credit;
```

By :

```
$nom = "example";
```

I got :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: example is not define.

Comment: Is the code you posted meant to be PHP, or JavaScript? It's not clear which, the first foreach looks like PHP, and the function looks like JavaScript. What's going on? XD

Comment: add quotes around the arguments: `"<a onClick='modification(\"".$id."\",\"".$nom."\",\"".$prix."\");'>"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your php code results in something like

```
<a onClick='modification(3, example, 25);'>
```

which makes the javascript interpreter believe that "example" is the name of a variable. You need to enclose it in quotes so that javascript interprets it as a string.

```
<a onClick='modification(3, "example", 25);'>
```

I assume $id and $prix are always numbers, and numbers should not be quoted and will not appear as variable names to the javascript interpreter.

The reason why you get a different error message when $nom contains an accent is that a variable name with an accent is invalid, and the interpreter discovers the invalid identifier before it discovers that the variable is undefined.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'm stuck on this since 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the JavaScript cannot find variable with 'example' name , try

$nom = "'example'";